# Retrieve transferred file size from AWS S3 put_object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, filesize

I have code to upload a file to AWS S3 in Python using `boto3.client` and `put_object` like (example below assumes JSON data):

```
def snapshot(data, path):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
    r = s3_client.put_object(
        Body=bytes(json.dumps(data, indent=2, default=str).encode("utf-8")),
        ContentType="application/json",
        Bucket=BUCKET,
        Key=path + ".json"
    )

    *** Return r.fileSize or something like that ***
```

In looking through the documentation for `boto3` and for the AWS S3 API, I don't see any way to retrieve the file size of the transferred object.

Is there any way to retrieve this without an additional interaction with S3 (i.e. reading file size from the newly uploaded file), and without simply using Python to get the size of the object passed?

Comment: Well, you know the size of the object you put, and if it returns okay then even aside from the checksum in the response, you know the size is the size of what you put. I'm probably overlooking your meaning, but you can just use the python os utilities to state the file size. I know you say without using python, but I can't tell what you're after. If you don't want to check your file like object locally, and you don't want to call S3 again...?

Comment: @theherk yep I understand that (hence my ending with "and without simply using Python to get the size of the object passed")—not a huge issue I was just specifically asking if there was some way I did not see to determine the actual volume as acknowledged by the boto3 client. I'm not really familiar with interpreting checksum; it looks like there are multiple hashed checksum values available via the put_object response?

Comment: If you're hoping for a content size given back, there isn't. But there isn't any information you lack... as long as you get a success back. The etag can compare between versions, but without calling the api again to get it, even that isn't helpful. Sorry.

Comment: Just to be explicit, the [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) doesn't return a size.  Beyond the work to decide when to break out to a multipart upload, boto3 has no reason to track the size, so it doesn't.  If you need the information, just ask the bytes object you're creating.

Comment: @AnonCoward yep understood—although I would argue that boto3 has a reason to track size if its users would like it to track size.

Comment: @OJT why though? I can't think of even a contrived situation where you don't have this information. Its users have the size, for they have the object.